What happens when expressing a function into a series?
Questions emerged from a simple question:
What is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x})^{n}$ , where $x \in \mathbb{C}$ ?
In one point of view, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x})^{n}=\frac{-2x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-2nx^{n}$, which implies the answer to be $-20$. 
In the other point of view, the sum is apparently divergent. Then what happened in this procedure? 
BTW, if we use Laurent Series instead of normal series, will the outcome fit the result?
At last, will the same thing happen with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{a}{4})^n}$, where $a=2$ or $-1$?

The collection of "formal power series " is a ring, bt we can't define multiplication on all Laurent series, because you need infinite sums to converge where they might not, in general. There might be cases where the infinite Laurent series  make a useful extension fo generating functions, but it is unclear how.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x})^{n}$ converges for complex $x$ near $x=i$.

For example, you can define $f(x)=\sum n^nx^n$ as a formal power series, even thoough it doesn't converge for any non-zero $x.$ But Laurent series are harder.

If we expand each term in your sum, the constant terms become: $\sum\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}n,$ which doesn't converge.

If $\mathbb R[[x]]$ is the ring of formal power series in $x,$ you also can't find an automorphism  of $\mathbb R[[x]]$sending $x\mapsto x+a$ for  anynon-zero $a.$  This means that you can't always convert a power series around $1$ to a power series around $0.$

Now, $$\sum_{n\geq0} x^n=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^{n-1}(x-2)^n.\tag1$$ Those two power series are in different rings of formal power series, so we can't say that they are "equal" as formal power series, even though, in some sense, they are equal as functions.
Indeed, (1) makes sense in the ring of power series over any ring, even a ring where infinite sums do not make sense, like $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z.$ What it really means there is that if we multiply the left and right sides by the polynomial $1-x=-(1+x-2)$ in their respective rings, we get $1.$
So, the problem is, the infinite sum you've written is not defined as a formal power series of $x,$ so we can't really ask what the coefficient o $x^n$ is. There might be times where two functions may be equal, but here we are treating $1-x$ as a polynomial of $x$ and $-(1+(x-2))$ as a polynomial of $x-2.$

Fundamentally, the ring of formal power series over a ring $A$ is more algebra than analysis. There is one way to analytically think of it as adding an element such that $x^n$ goes to zero much faster than any sequence of elements in $A$ can grown - essentially, we are adding $x$ as an infinitesimal.
The ring of power series doesn't let us do evaluation, in general. If $f(x),g(x)$ are in $A[[x]],$, we can't in general define $f(g(x)).$ But we can can compute $f(xg(x)).$

The problem with formal Laurent series is that they do not form a ring. You can't always multiply two Laurent series and get a new Laurent series, because the terms you come up with are necessarily infinite sums, not all of which converge to zero.
Indeed, formally, $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x^{-1}}{1-x^{-1}}+\frac1{1-x}=0.$$ So a formal Laurent series function doesn't have a unique formula.
We can take $A[[x]][x^{-1}],$ which allows finitely many negative terms, and that is even a field, if $A$ is a field.
